# Gradle error with compile 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android-extras:0.6.1'

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, mapsforge

im building an app with mapsforge, im adding to my map proyect the 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android-extras:0.6.1' library, but gradle cant sync.

this is my gradle code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "safeapp.safe"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'

    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.5.2'
    compile 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-core:0.6.1'
    compile 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android:0.6.1'
    compile 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android-extras:0.6.1'
    compile 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-awt:0.6.1'
    compile 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-reader:0.6.1'
    compile 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-writer:0.6.1'
    compile 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map:0.6.1'
    compile 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.2.2-beta-1'
    compile 'com.kitfox.svg:svg-salamander:1.0'
    compile 'net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0'
}
```

and this is the gradle error

```
Error:Failed to resolve: android.support:compatibility-v4:23.2.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem

The problem arises from the mapsforge-map-android-extras dependencies in Maven / jCenter centrals (where is declared differently as jar vs aar).

To overcome that annoyance you can declare it in Gradle as a non transitive dependency:

```
compile('org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android-extras:0.6.0') {
    transitive = false
}
```

there is the link

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mapsforge-dev/d39AA3SJuQE/TtMPUbWcCwAJ